# Button with sup and sub text won't click

Tags: javascript, html, button

I have this button code.

```
<button id="plusminus" class="key topcolor" value="plusminus"><sup>+</sup>/<sub>−</sub></button>
```

I noticed that I can click the button just fine except when I accidentally click on the sup and sub text (`+` and `-`), then it won't perform the action. I can click on `/` to perform the action with no problem.

Why is it doing this? I looked online everywhere and I couldn't find much info. How do I fix this?

P.S. The button is part of the javascript calculator that I'm coding. This button is supposed to convert the number to negative number.

Here's the link to my Javascript calculator: https://codepen.io/kikibres/pen/MWyyBxJ?editors=1010

Comment: Which browser are you using? In Firefox and Chrome the button is pressed wherever I click.

Comment: I suspect the problem is more in how you bound your js event, there's no reason a click on the text would not cause a bubbled event to the button. Can you share that code as well?

Comment: Here's my code: https://codepen.io/kikibres/pen/MWyyBxJ?editors=1010

Comment: Found a solution - see my answer.
Seems it's local to codepen.  I'd send them a possible bug/not handled-report.
Using `z-index` to bury "+" and "-" under the button...

Comment: I'd remove the `padding` from the CSS `.wrapper` because it messes with `height: 100%` and causes scrollbar and need for scrolling.

Comment: This CodePen is not true HTML/CSS/JS and is exponentially irritating me...!
After removing `padding` from `.wrapper`, you'd need to uncomment `height: 100%` from `body`...
Who knows how much unnecessary extra code CodePen makes it's users use...

Comment: Bottom line: your code works, you are a very good programmer, and I will never recommend CodePen to anyone - even their reply to my report on your issue was full of excuses, finger-pointing at "js quirks" instead of thanking for pointing out the issue and that they are on it to fix/implement!

Comment: Yeah, while I do like Codepen, I will have to use other online editors sometimes such as CodeSandBox, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to not work on codepen only(?) == Your code is fine!
Got it to work!

CSS - add the following:

```
.plusminus {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}
.plusminussupsub {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

HTML - modify the following:
`<button id="plusminus" class="key topcolor plusminus" value="plusminus"><sup class="plusminussupsub">+</sup>/<sub class="plusminussupsub">−</sub></button>`

Possible explanation:
click events (in codepen only?) don't go up from `<sup>` and `<sub>` elements.
Solution:
push them behind/under the button using `z-index` (which works only for non-static positioning, hence `position: relative;` + `top: 0;` and `left: 0;` so it would (not) be offset to where intended).

---

For trials:

- works on my Chrome(V85)/Win10

```html
<button
  id="plusminus"
  class="key topcolor"
  value="plusminus"
  onclick="console.log('clicked at '+(new Date().valueOf()))"
><sup>+</sup>/<sub>−</sub></button>
```

Comment: Okay, so your code is working, so it has something to do with my javascript code after all? Here's my js calculator code: https://codepen.io/kikibres/pen/MWyyBxJ?editors=1010. Can you help me figure it out please?

Comment: Does your code work on your browser NOT ON CODEPEN?
If so - that's the problem!
Anyways, found a fix - see (edited) answer...

Comment: Got it to work in Codepen. Thanks for your help! I had thought it has something to do with Javascript but didn't even think that it was a css bug in Codepen. I will have to become more diligent in my troubleshooting skills. As for the padding, I did what you suggested but had to put them back because it didn't look good when I follow your suggestions.

Comment: Glad to hear!
* did you see my suggestion about `body { height: 100%...` AND without the `padding`?

Answer (score 0):

- this works for me(i am using google chrome)

  ```
  const button = document.getElementById("plusminus");


  button.addEventListener("click", function(){
      document.body.style.background = "red"; // just using this for testing
      // do your code to convert to a negative number here
  });
  ```